# AS3 game single-swf preloader with SWCs

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, preloader, swc

I have this game I'm trying to build a preloader for. Because of how flash portals work, it all has to be within a single swf file, so as far as I know preloader swf -> game swf is not an option.

I generally use the "Preloader on frame 1", export classes on frame 2 and all, but this time the project is so big I've split it across multiple swc.

My main .fla is set to export of frame 2, my swc are also set to export on frame 2, but for some reason the preloader always remains blank until the very end. My guess is the swc are being loaded directly on frame 1 when they shouldn't.

Any way around this besides putting everything in a single library?

Comment: swcs are not loaded, what do you think they are?

Comment: What do you mean? I'm including swc which hold my assets into my project, they end up in the resulting swf, my only problem is that they seem to load before the preloader.

Comment: they are included in your project, they are never loaded.

Comment: And that project is loaded by the end user, hence the preloader. I'm not asking how to load a swc, I'm asking how to move its content to load on frame 2 as you would with other assets in a single swf preloader.

Comment: I don't know how else to say it, swc are not loaded ever, not on frame 1, not on frame 2, not on frame 9999, they are never ever loaded into your project, they are part of it to start with.

Comment: The resulting swf -is- loaded by the player though, with the swc content, so I know the swc isn't "loaded" BY the swf, but in the end the user downloads it all so I don't know what that changes. My problem is the swcs content seems to be loading before the preloader on frame 1 is ever shown.

So normally I put preloader code on frame 1, export classes and assets on frame 2 and voilà. First time using swcs, and their content always seem to be loaded before frame 1, even when specified otherwise.

Comment: About your point with flash portals - at least Kongregate allows multiple files to be uploaded as a single game, so you can use a preloader in there.

Comment: Good to know, but I would still want my game to have a preloader on portals that would only grab the main game file.

Comment: Are you referencing any content from the swc in frame 1?

Comment: No, frame 1 is nothing but preloader code and on-stage assets like a progress bar. No document class to the project, and the "main" class is instantiated on frame 2.

Comment: If you do `Publish settings - Generate size report` and then publish your project, what is the size of your frame 1? (This option is for Flash CS, but a tool should be available to determine this data from a published SWF directly.) If it's almost the entire SWF, then you have some assets published in the first frame and not the second.

Comment: I checked in FlashDevelop and frame 1 was ~12mb out of 15mb in total. Pretty much exactly the weight of my various swc vs what was directly in the .fla file.

And like I said, the content in the .fla goes on frame 2, it's everything that is in the swc that refuses to be loaded anywhere but on frame 1.